# Static build of Qt - Plugin class name could not be determined for qwayland-egl plugin

Tags: qt, ubuntu-14.04, static-libraries, qt5.5

```
$ /opt/Qt5.5/5.5-static/bin/qmake yyyy.pro
Project WARNING: Plugin class name could not be determined for qwayland-egl plugin.
Project WARNING: Plugin class name could not be determined for qwayland-generic plugin.
```

I statically built Qt 5.5.1. I don't have qtcreator. I want to understand what Is this qwayland-egl plugin about and what is the way to link it to static qt?

Am I supposed to run: ./configure -static -qwayland-egl while compiling qt?

Comment: I also am wondering about this. I added a new kit in Qt Creator and am receiving this error message.